# Simple Carousel Component in React

Tags: reactjs

API that I am trying to design:

```
<Carousel>
  <CarouselItem><any arbitrary HTML here></CarouselItem>
  <CarouselItem><any arbitrary HTML here></CarouselItem>
  <CarouselItem><any arbitrary HTML here></CarouselItem>
</Carousel>
```

---

Each `<CarouselItem/>` is supposed to have a `next` button, So, my `<CarouselItem/>` render function looks like this:

```
<div className="carousel-item">
  {this.props.children}
  <div onClick={this.nextSlide}>
    Next
  </div>
</div>
```

My `<Carousel/>` component's job is to render only 1 `CarouselItem` at a time and jump to the next one when a click happens.

I am able to render a single `CarouselItem` but I am having trouble wiring up a click handler to the `CarouselItem` inside `Carousel`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CarouselItem from './carousel-item'

class Carousel extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)

    this.state = {
      currentIndex: -1,
      currentItem: null
    }

    this.activateSlideAtIndex = this.activateSlideAtIndex.bind(this)
  }

  findItemAtIndex(index) {
    return this.props.children.find((carouselItemComponent)=> carouselItemComponent.props.item.index === index)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.activateSlideAtIndex(this.state.currentIndex)
  }

  activateSlideAtIndex(index) {
    let newCarouselItemComponent = this.findItemAtIndex(index+1)
    if (newCarouselItemComponent) {
      newCarouselItemComponent.props.onClick = this.activateSlideAtIndex
     //Complains here that Cannot assign to read only property 'onClick' of object '#<Object>'
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: index+1,
        currentItem: newCarouselItemComponent
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="carousel">
        {this.state.currentItem}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Carousel
```

I understand that I cannot override the `props` of a child component. How am I supposed to achieve what I want then? All help is appreciated.

Comment: I would like to suggest `react-slick` if you don't mind use third-party libraries and prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This is a sample problem. I am trying to understand how higher order components are typically constructed in React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't store the entire selected component in state, I would store the selected index and then render based off that. Something like:

```
render() {
  <div>
    {this.props.children[this.state.currentIndex]}
  </div>
}
```

hm but in terms of adding to the props of those children.. it looks like [this article](http://jaketrent.com/post/send-props-to-children-react/) discusses it.